# deploy python 3.5 and django 1.10 on windows

Tags: django, iis, web-deployment, windows-server-2012-r2

So I am using python 3.5 with django 1.10 and finished developing a small project and ready for deploy. Right now I have a Windows server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 already set up so I tried that first. I followed [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/366348/how-to-set-up-django-with-iis-8) tutorial but failed. I think it is because that I am using python 3.5 but the fastCGI 2.1 Gateway only support up to 3.4. Now I am wondering if there is alternative way to deploy on a local windows server with my version of python and django? I know Azure has good support for this but I have to do this locally.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course. https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, FastCGI is deprecated since version 1.7.